# Picture height change or resize

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, image

I am programming spirit-safe.de, but I think the image is too high so I want to reduce the height. Do I best do this via CSS? Cant find the image in my Ruby on Rails code hence it must be in CSS I think or something.

No clue of Front-End :-)

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you are talking about your main image inside page-header container. Somewhere in your CSS files, you have this:

```css
.page-header--hero.-main {
    background-image: url(/assets/hero/img03_xl-326aaa5….jpg);
    max-width: 1920px;
    height: 900px;
}
```

That's where you are setting the image and height, just change them.